# How to do Javascript debug logging

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, logging

I am writing an Angular app, with bit and pieces of JQuery plugins around the place.

Some of the logic is pretty complex and I'd like to have some debug logging that I can leave in the codebase that won't print out to the console in production.

What are people using to achieve this these days? I know Angular has its own logging but this logging needs to be across both the Angular stuff and the JQuery stuff. I can't rewrite the JQuery to be 'angularised'.

How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try chrome develop tools?

WIN： <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

MAC: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.

sources - > your script - >  double click to add a breakpoint  -> refresh

[Here is a shortcut.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK7td.png)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely breakpoints but you also need to check out

[Batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang) - chrome extension developed by angular team.  I find it extremely useful for scope inheritance.  It does crash now and then but it is still quite useful.